# access to instance profile within CodeBuild Windows image

Tags: aws-codebuild

I am trying to execute terraform configuration from within CodeBuild's curated image `aws/codebuild/windows-base:2019-2.0`. Terraform's AWS provider is not able to access the default profile configuration, which is usually present if we use ubuntu or amazon linux images.

Is there an additional configuration that is needed to get access to the default profile.

Additional context: I am building dotnet 6.0 project prior to execution of the terraform plan & dotnet 6 runtime is only available with Windows base image. As a last option, I would split the build & deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Answer my question, starting from v4 AWS terraform provider enforces precedence of authentication specification i.e. if we set `profile` in  `provider aws {...}` then provider will not fallback to environment if the profile does not exist.